# Not able to Log out From yahoo API using javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, logout, yahoo-api

Hello everyone,
               I'm using Yahoo Login API to perform Login and Logout operations here I'm able to successfully login by using the following code but i'm not able to log out however the application is refreshed but in a new tab when i open yahoo i'm still signed in.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/hzUqL/1/) is the fiddle of what i did

```
 YUI().use('login', function(Y) {
 Y.login.renderLoginButton('login');
 });
```

Can anyone help me in how to sing out or provide me a alternate solution of login and logout for yahoo using javascript.

I've implemented using openId approach does that create the issue?

Comment: that api would not log you out of the actual yahoo website, it logs the user out of your framework so that calls to yahoo for that user from your framework are no longer usable for that session.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so then do you any Idea what should i use to accomplish login and logout both?

Comment: Just do what the docs tell you to do, im just telling you your method of checking wither you are logged out is wrong, as going to yahoo's website wont tell you if you are signed out of your sites "login with yahoo" thing. Its the same with Login with facebook, if you login to a site by using login with facebook and then on that same site logout, it doesnt log you out on facebook itself.

Answer (score 0):

Single Sign On does not comply with Single Log Out. This is as per Signle Sign On design.